# replace multiple values in a column and keep other values unchanged in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an example dataframe like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['red', 'orange', 'blue'],
                   'value': [22,44,66]})

    name    value
0   red     22
1   orange  44
2   blue    66
```

I need to replace `red` with `1` and `blue` with `2`, leaving `orange` as it is, in the column `name`.

I use map function like below:

```
df.name.map({'red': 0, 'blue': 1})
```

I got result like:

```
    name    value
0   0.0     22
1   NaN     44
2   1.0     66
```

In the column, `orange` becomes `NaN`

What is the best way to replace the values?
I do not want to use `df.name.str.replace(..)` many times to replace many values. In my real data, there are 10 values to replace in a column. 
Thanks.

Comment: Use `df["name"].replace({'red': 0, 'blue': 1})`.

Comment: How about mapping orange to orange: `df.name.map({'red': 0, 'blue': 1, 'orange': 'orange'})`

Comment: this is just an example. Real data has many values to keep. You cannot just list everyone of them. @shash678

Comment: Your answer works.  If you put it as answer, I will accept it.  @Henry Yik

Comment: @zesla added as answer with link to docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
print (df["name"].replace({'red': 0, 'blue': 1}))

0         0
1    orange
2         1
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Fix your code with `fillna`

```
df.name = df.name.map({'red': 0, 'blue': 1}).fillna(df.name)
0         0
1    orange
2         1
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

One way can be creating your custom `dict` and overiding `__missing__`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['red', 'orange', 'blue'],
               'value': [22,44,66]})

class Foo(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
       return key
df.name.map(Foo({'red': 0, 'blue': 1}))
```

From the documentation [Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)
:

> When arg is a dictionary, values in Series that are not in the dictionary (as keys) are converted to NaN. However, if the dictionary is a dict subclass that defines **missing** (i.e. provides a method for default values), then this default is used rather than NaN.